# Where is overall K/D ratio found in Black Ops Multiplayer?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I've found both map and gun specific ratios but not an overall ratio. Where is it hiding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Operations -> Playercard -> Combat Record -> Weapons (Combat Summary)

Comment: So much info is thrown at you... thought the was gun specific. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just check the Leaderboards which will show your ratio compared to your friends/everyone elses.

Comment: It looks like that's only for specific game types.

Answer (score 1):

Leaderboards TDM shows the total kills and deaths of the team (everyone on the team you're on) That's the reason you have 13,000K